# Wordpress subdomains keeping subdomain URL in the address bar

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to use `a.page.com` instead of `page.com/a` (permalink to page "a"), but using `.htaccess` I think the rule just loops and WP always redirects the user to `page.com/a`

Same with “automatic subdomains” plugin. I tried disabling canonical redirection too.

What I just want is to keep `a.page.com/args` as the URL

Comment: Do you have access to the Apache config? I know you can rewrite /a to a.

Comment: Hi, I don't have access to apache, just cpanel. What I have tried is to create the subdomains pointing to wp root and installed automatic subdomains plugins, that works but if you type a.page.com you get redirected always to page.com/a

Also I have tried with:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.page\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /a/$1 [PT]`

But I am guessing that it calls /a/ and the wp sentence in .htaccess takes ownership (to resolve the permalink /a/ and redirects the user again). I don't want to move Wordpress, just to "hide" the subdomains